# How to unpack a .zip file in Windows Mobile?

Tags: windows-mobile, zip, mobile-phones, unzip

I need to programaticaly unpack a zip archive to folder on Windows Mobile. Is there an easy to use API that I can use directly or should I go with some external library?

Answer (score 7):

You need an external library.  There is a zlibce.dll, a native DLL that you can use if C++ is your thang.

If .NET is your thing then I can recommend [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com), which runs on the .NETCF 2.0, is free, open source, and has good doc, good performance.  In the DotNetZip source distrib, there's a CF-Unzipper project that you can view and compile; it demonstrates how to unzip files on the device.  Here's a link where you can [view the code](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/29776#380835) for the device app.

This is a snip of the zip-relevant parts of the code.  It unzips to a directory that takes its name from the zip file (without the .zip extension).

```
    private void UnzipSelectedFile()
    {
        string parent = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(_selectedpath);
        string dir = System.IO.Path.Combine(parent,
            System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(_selectedpath));
        try
        {
            using (var zip1 = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile(_selectedpath))
            {
                foreach (var entry in zip1)
                {
                    entry.Extract(dir, true);
                }
            }

            // re-populate the treeview with the extracted files:
            AddChildren(tvFolders.SelectedNode.Parent);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception! " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Here's a link to [an online version of the doc](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp) for the library.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .Net Compact Framework you could go with http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib. I believe it supports running on CF.

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of what language you use you can use [Info-ZIP](http://www.info-zip.org/) as an external executable.

Comment: As per http://www.info-zip.org/FAQ.html#WinCE - `We currently have no plans to do a WinCE port of Zip. We'd like to do one eventually, but only if time permits, and it has been on hold for more than eight(!) years. Don't hold your breath, eh?`